# Azure Flexible MySQL server aborting all connections sometimes

Tags: mysql, azure

Good evening,

Sometimes all my connections to the database are shut down. I run several NodeJS programs that use a database pool and use DataGrip. None of those is able to connect (it gives the error handshake failed). If I take a look at the metrics on Azure Portal, the only thing I can see is that even Azure lost connection to the database (See the picture).
It's an Flexibile Azure database with Burstable and Standard_B1Ms as configuration.
What is the best way to debug this and prevent the connections from aborting again?

[image: Azure Portal Metrics]

It seems like it happens around every 1.5 hours:

[image]

Comment: Are there any events around the 5pm mark in the Activity Log?

Comment: @esqew, sadly no it's completely empty beside some server configuration changes (not around that time)

Comment: What does the [Scheduled maintenance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/concepts-maintenance) configuration look like for this server? Is it possible that maintenance activities necessitating a restart kill these connections and the calling applications don't have sufficient logic to re-establish said connections? Are there any start/stop schedules that you may have forgotten about?

Comment: @esqew I also checked that. The maintenance schedule is set on saturday night. But the connection abortings happen a few times a day. See the updated question^